# go test error - no test files - error in GOPATH

Tags: go

In the below environment:

```
code$ pwd
/home/user1/code
code$ echo $GOPATH
/home/user1/golib:/home/user1/code
code$ ls
bin  pkg  src 
code$ ls src/github.com/myhub/codingtest/
main.go  test_main.go
code$ 
code$ 
code$ 
code$ 
code$ 
code$ cat src/github.com/myhub/codingtest/test_main.go 
package main

import "testing"

func TestSplit(t *testing.T) {
        gotAllButLast, gotLast := split(2013)
        wantAllButLast := 201
        wantLast := 3
        if gotAllButLast != wantAllButLast {
                t.Errorf("got %d but expected %d", gotAllButLast, wantAllButLast)
        }
        if wantLast != gotLast {
                t.Errorf("got %d but expected %d", gotLast, wantLast)
        }
}
code$ 
code$ 
code$ 
code$ 
code$ 
code$ cat src/github.com/myhub/codingtest/main.go 
package main

// Spit n into all but its last digit and its last digit
func split(n int) (int, int) {
        return n / 10, n % 10
}

func main() {

}
code$
```

---

`go test` gives below error:

```
code$ go test github.com/myhub/codingtest
?       github.com/myhub/codingtest   [no test files]
code$ 
code$ 
code$ 
code$ 
code$ 
code$
```

---

How to resolve `no test files error`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To resolve your error you need to rename test_main.go to main_test.go

As you can see [in the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/)

> To write a new test suite, create a file whose name ends _test.go